# Print everything on line after match

Tags: bash, grep

I have a large text file that contains a unique string in the middle. I want to print everything AFTER the string by using grep.

```
cat textfile | grep "target_string"
This highlights target_string but prints the whole file

cat textfile | grep -o "target_string"
This prints only target_string

cat textfile | grep -o "target_string*"
This prints only target_string
```

How can I print everything after "target_string" and nothing before?

Comment: By "everything", you mean just everything ON THAT LINE, right?  It looks like a lot of people interpreted your question to mean THE REST OF THE FILE.

Comment: I added an answer to print everything after the string ON THAT LINE, and not the rest of the file

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You forgot the '.' in the regular expression:

```
cat textfile | grep -o "target_string.*"
```

Comment: No need for `cat`, you can directly `grep` the file.

Comment: The `awk` solution seems substantially more flexible and useful.

Comment: Tip: use in conjunction with `-h` if you need to drop a filename prefix also. (e.g. if doing `find | grep` )

Comment: I like this answer but with a small tweak: `cat testfile | grep -o "After and including.*" | grep "highlight"`

Answer (score 53):

Strangely, the accepted answer printed out the whole line, where I just wanted all the info after the target string.  This worked for me:

```
sed -n 's/target_string//p' filename
```

Adapted from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern)

Comment: This assumes `target_string` is at the beginning of line.  You can change the regex to `.*target_string` to fix that.

Answer (score 36):

With GNU `grep`, try `-B0 -A999999999` or similar.  A better choice might be `awk`:

```
awk '/target_string/ {seen = 1}
     seen            {print}'
```

If (your problem specification is slightly unclear) you don't also need to print the matching line, `sed` is even shorter:

```
sed '1,/target_string/d'
```

Comment: The sed line worked perfectly for what I needed, thanks!

Comment: You can also use `-C 3` to get the lines around the line - I completely forgot about these options!

Comment: This is extremely useful info, and exactly what *I'm* looking for, but I'm pretty sure the OP only wanted to match *the rest of the line*.  It's not immediately obvious at first glance, but if you read the question carefully I think this shows through. ("Print everything *on line* after match" instead of "Print everything *after matching line*")  Of course it's also possible that this clarification (or obfuscation?) was the result of edits made after you answered...

Answer (score 6):

This will print everything after each match, on that same line only:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /target_string(.*)/' textfile
```

This will do the same, except it will also print all subsequent lines:

```
perl -lne 'if ($found){print} else{if (/target_string(.*)/){print $1; $found++}}' textfile
```

Comment: I wanted to print the rest of a single line after a pattern. And the first one worked well. None of the other answers helped. This was to remove everything before a particular directory in a path.